# how to modify access restrictions for tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can we modify or customize people who can view the changes made by us to the SVN repo? Is there any option when we commit our changes, which can be modified to change the list of people who can view our changes?

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client. It's a server's task to put such restrictions. Apache Subversion supports [path-based authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) and you could configure No Access, Read and Read Write access rules on paths in your repositories.

> How can we modify or customize people who can view the changes made by
>   us to the SVN repo?

Deploy Subversion server and use path-based authorization to implement access control.